# Prove whether the statements are true or false

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> (1) If {$b_{n}$} is convergent, where $b_{n} = a_{n}a_{n+1}$, then ${a_{n}}$ is convergent.
>
> (2) If $a_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty $, then {$\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots+a_{2n}}{\sqrt n}$} is convergent.

This is what I have so far,

For number 1, I came up with a few examples that show the statement could possibly true, but I'm not sure how to even start my proof

For number 2, since $a_{n}$ converges to 0, the numerator will eventually stop increasing. However, the denominator will keep growing as $n \to \infty$. Hence, the sequence will eventually converge to 0.

Comment: Both of your guesses are wrong. Both of the claims are false. Try to come up with counterexamples.

Comment: Do you even know that the statements are true? What about this sequence:$$a_n=10^{(-1)^n}+\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{2}$$,$a_n$ is not converging, but $b_n\to 1$

Comment: Thats not what the question is asking... It states $a_{n}$ is also convergent

Answer (score 2):

For the first: take $a_{n}= (-1)^{n}$ as counterexample.

Comment: Doesn't that diverge though?

Comment: bn converges to -1, an diverges, thus it is a counterexample to the statement that was asked to be proven or disproven.

Comment: $(-1)^{n}$ **oscillates constantly**, we won't say it's converging.  If $a_{n}$ converges to $L$, then $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{n}-L|<\epsilon$, $\forall n\ge N$

Comment: That is the point,though. To be clear, an is $(-1)^{n}$

Comment: You should mention which are $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ clearly.